# Highlight some bytes in a string

Tags: python, string, hex

I have a list like following:

> \xeb\x1f\x5e\x31\xdb\x88\x5e\x07\x89\x76\x08\x89\x5e\x0c\x8d\x1e\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\x31\xc0\xb8\x0b\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\x31\xf6\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x41\x42\x42\x42\x42\x43\x43\x43\x43

I want to find `\x00` and `\xcd\x80` in the string and print it in highlight style. (for example with red color.). How can I do that?

Comment: highlight how? are you just using IDLE/console?

Comment: Does the string contains *escaped parts*, or unescaped?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the string is like something i put in the topic.

Comment: @depperm I am using terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If the string `s` is **unescaped** (the `\` are real, characters), you can for instance use:

```
print(s.replace(r'\x00','\x1b[31m\\x00\x1b[0m') \
       .replace(r'\xcd\x80','\x1b[31m\\xcd\\x80\x1b[0m'))
```

What we do here is look for the *raw* string `r'\x00'` and replace it by `'\x1b[31m\\\x00\x1b[0m'`. This means we prepend it with `'\x1b[31m'`, the [ANSI terminal escape code for red foreground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) and append it with `'\x1b[0m'`, the [ANSI terminal escape code for dropping markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

If I run this code with your string on my console, I get:

[image]

Now this is of course not very convenient. So you can use:

```
def print_highlight(s,markers=(r'\x00',r'\xcd\x80')):
    for marker in markers:
        s = s.replace(marker,'\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m'%marker)
    print(s)
```

So now you can give it the string `s`, together with a list of string fragments you want to highlight. For example:

```
print_highlight(string,(r'\x31',))
```

will highlight all `\x31` parts.

Comment: I used the command print(string.replace(r'\xcd\x80','\033[91m\\xcd\\x80\x1b[0m') or string.replace((r'\x00','\033[91m\\x00\x1b[0m'))). it just highlight \xcd\x80 and for second one it doesn't work. where is the problem?

Comment: @WolfHowling: you need to chain them together. In the last case, you opened an additional bracket in the `replace`. As a result you pass a tuple to the replace, and not two strings.